# Cannot access port of Jetty Server

Tags: java, server, jetty

I have the problem that I get a 504 if I try to access the Jetty Server on my private server. The exact message is "ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a complete response for this request. Server returned 0 bytes.".

I create the server with

```
        ContextHandler context = new ContextHandler("/");
        SessionHandler sessions = new SessionHandler(new HashSessionManager());
        sessions.setHandler(new WebHandler(this));
        context.setHandler(sessions);

        // Setup the server
        final Server server = new Server(getConfig().getInt("server.port"));
        server.setSessionIdManager(new HashSessionIdManager());
        server.setHandler(sessions);
        server.setStopAtShutdown(true);

        // Start listening
        getProxy().getScheduler().runAsync(this, new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    server.start();
                    getLogger().warning("Webserver started on URI: " + server.getURI() + ", state: " + server.getState());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    getLogger().warning("Unable to bind web server to port.");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

If I start the server on localhost all things work well, but if I put it on my private Hetzner server (Debian 10) I get the error I've written above. The firewall is set to accept all ports. If I create a tunnel to my server via ssh the site loads infinitely long without showing a result.

I hope you can help me :)

Edit: I saw that he tried to connect via IPv6. I forced it to use IPv4, but same result. Here's the netstat output:
`tcp6       0      0 :::8092                 :::*                    LISTEN      4581/java`

Comment: `server.start()` starts it's own threadpool and immediately returns.  don't wrap it in a async or a runnable or a scheduler.

Comment: The `WebHandler`, what is it?  If it's a `ServletHandler` then that's the reason for your issues.